# Apache CXF 2.3.0 WSDLToJava problem

Tags: cxf, wsdl2java

I'm trying out apachecxf 2.3.0 and i'm having problems using the wsdlToJava tool. No matter what, i get an WSDLToJava Error: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException. Tried an older version 2.1 and it works fine on the same WSDL.
Are anyone else having the same problem with this version?

Answer (score 7):

Add -frontend jaxws21 as jdk6 has 2.1 jaxb builtin while 2.3 is trying to use 2.2 jaxb(or put 2.2 jaxb into your jdk so it uses that instead of 2.1)....

```
      <java classname="org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava" fork="true" failonerror="true">
         <arg value="-impl"/>
         <arg value="-d"/>
         <arg value="${gen.src}"/>
         <arg value="-frontend"/>
         <arg value="jaxws21"/>
         <arg value="${input}/schemas/enrollment.wsdl"/>
         <classpath>
            <path refid="cxf.classpath"/>
         </classpath>
      </java>
```

Comment: Yep that did it for me. Hopefully this doesn't have any bad side effects? Good answer.

Comment: Hi I was having same problem as above, using CXF 2.3.0 and jdk6. I added -frontend jax21 but then I am getting error WSDLToJava Error: Could not find jaxws21 frontend within classpath             Any help on this will be really helpful